# asp.net grab selected form value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I get the selected value sent from the dropdownlist on the view from the controller?

Model:

```
public class CustomerInformation
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> State { get; set; }
    public CustomerInformation()
    {
        State = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            { 0, "California"},
            { 1, "Nevada"}
        };
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new CustomerInformation.Models.CustomerInformation();
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult ShowData(CustomerInformation.Models.CustomerInformation _customerInformation)
{
   //..
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowData", "Home"))
{
    @Html.Label("State:: ");
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(Model.State, "Key", "Value"))   
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `StateId` property for your model.  Then you can get that in your posted value...

```
public class CustomerInformation
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> State { get; set; }
 public int StateId {get;set;}   
 public CustomerInformation()
    {
        State = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            { 0, "California"},
            { 1, "Nevada"}
        };
    }
}
```

This is where you'll want to change the id and name of your html select list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateId, new SelectList(Model.State, "Key", "Value"))
```

Then in your Post method:

```
public ActionResult ShowData(CustomerInformation.Models.CustomerInformation _customerInformation)
{
   _customerInformation.StateId // The selected value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add to my model

```
public int id { get; set; }
```

to hold the imputed selected dropdown value

then in my view assign that value

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, new SelectList(Model.State, "Key", "Value"))
```